# ive set a global cookie for my domain and when user navigates to a page i want to check if that cookie exists; if not then it will give them a 404

Tags: php, cookies

Im trying to set a cookie for my domain via php so that once the user tries to navigate to another specific webpage that will require that cookie it will either allow them to view the html contents or block access.

This is what ive put in the cookie.php file where i set the cookie

```
`<?php
$cookie_name = 'jevans';
$cookie_value = "0042";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>`
```

This is the page i want protected and only accessible if the cookie is present

```
`<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
exit;
} else {
echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?> <html>content to be displayed</html>`
```

I expect for the script to check if the cookie exists and either allow or block based on whether they have that cookie.

Comment: In the protected page, where are you getting the $cookie_name from

Comment: i though php would accquire the cookie itself.. sorry im new to this

Comment: what would i have to add to that in order to get the cookie?

Comment: Are you using a get request or post request to access the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your protected page should look like this

```
<?php 
    $cookie_name = $_GET['cookie_name'] or $_POST['cookie_name'];

    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
         exit; 
    } else { 
         echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";     
         echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; 
    } 
?> <html>content to be displayed</html>
```

You use the $_GET for a get request or the $_POST for a post request.
A sample get request should look like this
 http://localhost/test/protectedpage.php?cookie_name=jevans